# How to get container danymicly in Jquery.post.callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some form **containers** with a form in each,

form.submit function like this:

```
$('.form-container form').submit(function(){
    $.post(url,data,callback);
});
```

callback function:

```
function callback(data){
    container.html(data);
}
```

Question is, how can I get the **container**, are there any way that I can pass it from submit function?

Because the container is **danymic**, I cann't simply get it by id or so.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what a "container" is in this sense, but if it's available in your submit function, then you can declare it in the submit function's local scope, and use it in the callback, either like so:

```
$('.form-container form').submit(function() {
    var container = ...; // your container
    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
        container.html(data);
    });
});
```

or if you prefer to keep the callback separate:

```
$('.form-container form').submit(function() {
    var container = ...;
    $.post(url, data, function(data) { callback(container, data); });
});

function callback(container, data) {
    container.html(data);
};
```

Comment: Thanks David, I just reallized that.

I declare container in the submit function and it's OK now.